# Can @ApplicationException's inheritance be overridden in EJB 3.1?

Tags: java, ejb-3.1

If I have an Exception with an @ApplicationException(inherited = true, rollback = true) but I want a subclass to not rollback. Can I just annotate the subclass with @ApplciationException(rollback = false)? Or will that not work? The spec doesn't seem to say, that I could find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The EJB 3.1 spec (JSR 318) does explain this in section 14.2.1.  There is an example:

```
In the following example :
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class ExceptionA extends RuntimeException
public class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA
@ApplicationException(inherited=false, rollback=false)
public class ExceptionC extends ExceptionB
public class ExceptionD extends ExceptionC

ExceptionA is an application exception with transaction rollback.
ExceptionB is an application exception with transaction rollback.
ExceptionC is an application exception without transaction rollback.
ExceptionD is not an application exception.
```

Comment: Good find @bkail. I incorporated this into my answer.

Comment: I saw that in the spec, but I misunderstood it when I read it, I thought that C was a new chain.

Answer (score 4):

[JSR 220](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_0-fr-spec-ejbcore.pdf) does not explicitly state what should happen in this scenario. It does specify that `application-exception` deployment descriptor elements will override any annotated value for a specific EJB:

> An application exception does not automatically result in marking the
>   transaction for rollback unless the ApplicationException annotation is
>   applied to the exception class and is speciﬁed with the rollback
>   element value true or the application-exception deployment descriptor
>   element for the exception speciﬁes the rollback element as true. The
>   rollback subelement of the application-exception deployment descriptor
>   element may be explicitly speciﬁed to override the rollback value
>   speciﬁed or defaulted by the ApplicationException annotation

This, combined with how annotations work for other Java EE components (`@TransactionAttribute`, `@ConcurrencyManagement` etc), would lead one to strongly assume that the subclass `@ApplicationException` annotation will override that of its parent. I confirmed this to be the case with a simple test (incomplete code shown):

```
@ApplicationException(inherited = true, rollback = true)
public class MyBaseException extends RuntimeException {
    // Constructors
}

public class MySubException1 extends MyBaseException {
    // Constructors
}

@ApplicationException(rollback = false)
public class MySubException2 extends MyBaseException {
    // Constructors
}

@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@Path("/misc/exception")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ExceptionResourceImpl {
   @Inject
   private BaseDAO baseDAO;

   public ExceptionResourceImpl() {
      super();
   }

   @GET
   @Path("/app/{id}")
   public Response getApplicationException(@PathParam("id") final String id) {
      final PaymentTypeModel model = new PaymentTypeModel();
      model.setPayment("Key" + System.currentTimeMillis());

      if ("1".equals(id)) {
         baseDAO.create(model);
         throw new MySubException1(
               "Throwing sub exception 1, default annotation behaviour");
      } else if ("2".equals(id)) {
         baseDAO.create(model);
         throw new MySubException2(
               "Throwing sub exception 2, overrides annotation behaviour");
      } else {
         return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
               .entity("Must supply id of 1 or 2").build();
      }
   }
}
```

Results:

- Requesting /misc/exception/app/1 results in an error on the screen, with no record saved to the database.
- Requesting /misc/exception/app/2 results in an error on the screen, but the record ***is*** saved to the database, aka the annotation override to not rollback transactions was processed for `MySubException2`.

---

*** EDIT ***

[JSR 318](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-pfd-spec.pdf) does clarify the behavior of inherited `ApplicationException` annotations, through the use of examples.

> In the following example :
>
> @ApplicationException(rollback=true) public class ExceptionA extends
>   RuntimeException
>
> public class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA
>
> @ApplicationException(inherited=false, rollback=false) public class
>   ExceptionC extends ExceptionB
>
> public class ExceptionD extends ExceptionC
>
> ExceptionA is an application exception with transaction rollback. 
>   ExceptionB is an application exception with transaction rollback.
>   ExceptionC is an application exception without transaction rollback.
>   ExceptionD is not an application exception

This confirms my original statements and testing.

Comment: thanks for the legwork. Which application server did you perform this test on?

Comment: Added extra information from JSR 318 into the answer. The expected behavior is guaranteed by the specification.